# FusedLocationProviderClient getLocationAvailability needs a delay to give a correct result

Tags: android, gps, location, availability

I'm trying to get last location checking first if GPS is enabled, I ask user to go to settings to enable it if it's not, and when I go back from settings  to my app, after enabling GPS location, and I check if GPS is available, I get it's not enabled, after a delay (1-2 seconds) I get it is.

Why there is that delay in fusedLocationProviderClient.getLocationAvailability() method? How can I solve it?
Here's the code:

```
@Inject
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    checkAndGetLastLocation();
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == GPS_ENABLE_REQUEST) {
        checkAndGetLastLocation();
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
private void checkAndGetLastLocation() {
    fusedLocationProviderClient.getLocationAvailability().addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), availabilityListener -> {
        if (availabilityListener.isSuccessful() && availabilityListener.getResult() != null && availabilityListener.getResult().isLocationAvailable()) {
            showProgress();
            getLastLocation();
        } else {
            showGPSDisabledDialog();
        }
    });
}

public void showGPSDisabledDialog() {
    hideProgress();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.gps_disabled_title);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.gps_disabled_message);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.enable_gps, (dialog, which) -> {
        dialog.dismiss();
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), GPS_ENABLE_REQUEST);
    }).setNegativeButton(R.string.not_enable_gps, (dialog, which) -> {
        switchToManualMode();
    });
    AlertDialog mGPSDialog = builder.create();
    mGPSDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mGPSDialog.show();
}

@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
private void getLastLocation() {
    locationListLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    addLocationButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    addLocationListLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    searchLocationsButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), locationListener -> {
                if (locationListener.isSuccessful() && locationListener.getResult() != null) {
                    Location lastLocation = locationListener.getResult();
                    locationStep1Presenter.getSites(lastLocation);
                } else {
                    Log.d(this.getTag(), "checkAndGetLastLocation:exception", locationListener.getException());
                    hideProgress();
                    showNoSitesToShowError();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: I think we've encountered the same issue, but on the getLastLocation() callback, as we're not checking getLocationAvailability() first. getLastLocation() returns an old (shall we say, cached?) location, instead of the current one. After another second call to this method do we actually receive the updated location. I believe this may be caused by the API using Google API client under the hood and having to first connect to it asynchronously before fetching the actual location. But I don't know if this is a bug or the intended behavior...